# redux dispatch action on every element of an array

Tags: reactjs, express, redux

I have an array of x element

> Arr (2) ['16', '149']

I need to dispatch an action on every Id in this array in order to find Object by Id.
My reducer for single Id is working and it is returning me value. But im lost.
This is my reducer

```
const initialState = {
  product: {},      
};
const productReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case GET_PRODUCT_BY_ID:
      return {
        ...state,
        product: action.payload,
      };
    
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

my action:

```
export const getProductById = (Id)=>async(dispatch)=>{
    try {
        const {data}= await api.getProductById(Id)
        dispatch({type:GET_PRODUCT_BY_ID, payload: data})
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
}
```

I would like to return something like array of objects with values for that id. Im stuck with this.

Comment: It's not clear. Do you want to get products by ids?

Comment: It's not clear for me what you want either. I also want to point out that your naming convention is lying about what your code does. I advise you to fix that first. I am almost certain you can figure out what to do next.